# how to access and set the value of server control in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am in need to access the hidden field and set its value to something, So that I can access the hidden field value in my C# code behind.

i used the following:

```
var a = document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("value", true);
```

but it is giving the `undefined or object is null` error.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

```
<asp:Button ID="backbtn" runat="server"  Text="Go Back" OnClientClick="CallConfirmBox('<%= TextBox2.ClientId %>)';" onclick="btnback_click" />
<br/> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            function CallConfirmBox(id) {
                var usrresponse;
                alert("in call confirm box called");
                if ('<%=this.test%>') {

                    var usrresponse = window.confirm("Do you want to go back without saving the data");
                }
                if (usrresponse) //userresponse is true
                {
                    alert(usrresponse);
                   window.location = window.location.href;
                }
                else
               {
                  var e  =document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("value",true);
                    alert(e)
                }
            }
     </script>
```

Comment: Use Client id like `Control.ClientID`

Answer (score 0):

Put everything iside

```
window.onload = function(){

     function CallConfirmBox(id) {
                  //your code
              }
}
```

Your accessing the element before DOM finish its loading.that's why you getting such error.

EDIT :

suppose id of button is `backbtn` as given in your html.

```
window.onload = function(){

         var CallConfirmBox = function (id) {
                      //your code
                  }

        var backBtn = document.getElementById('backbtn');

        backBtn.onclick = CallConfirmBox;

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Riyaj , i need to run the script at the button click event

Comment: Thanks Riyaj for reply ! what i want exactly is to when the callconfirmbox is get called at the click of backbtn, it will give confirm message such as do you want to go back without saving records, and whatever would be the userresponse it will save in textbox whixch is server control. Can you please suggest somthing so that i can save the useresponse in textbox in javascript

Comment: I think u r redirecting after true responce.It is not possible to save in the same html as it get overloaded.Use localStorage if u using html5 or cookies

Comment: By the way  u r reloading the same page.window.location = window.location.href;